# string value including negative value to Datetime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, c#-4.0, compare

I have a string value say for example

```
string a = "0";
string b = "-15";

DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

I want to compare if( a = d)
```

Basically, I want to use something like below

```
a.Date == d.Date
```

As mentioned the string number could be any positive or negative small numbers say 1 to 50 for example and that represents "days". 0 means today. -14 means 2 weeks ago.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding the last paragraph

Comment: @TheGeneral: I mean a is a string value. a could have value as a="0" which means today in business rule. a=-15 means 15 days ago in business rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
string a = "0";
string b = "-15";

DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

if (d.AddDays(int.Parse(a)) == d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} does equal {1}!", d.AddDays(int.Parse(a)), d);
}
```

This will convert a to an int, then add it to d, then compare to d. If you used b instead then you'd add -15 to d which is the same as subtracting 15.

If you want to assign the result of the calculation to a variable, then just do that first:

```
string a = "0";
string b = "-15";

DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
DateTime e = d.AddDays(int.Parse(a));
if (e == d)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} does equal {1}!", e, d);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: you are comparing add days to datetime

Comment: Add days returns a datetime.

Comment: Thank you, how about if a is a variable and can contain positive or negative value? Automatically your code works?

Comment: I edited the console.writeline to show how it works. As long as the string is a valid integer it will work. If you need validation/etc then just add it before doing the comparison. I put an edit in, but if the variable is negative, it just adds a negative value which deducts it. 
It's valid code, copy it into a basic console app and play with it.

Comment: thanks, your answer is good but I am trying to understand using two different variables rather than using same variable d. I cant understand quite with using same variable, can it be more readable?

Comment: I am happy with your answer, thank you, accept it in 3 mins as it has wait time

Comment: Added a second example which I think does what you want to see.

Comment: Exactly :) In layman terms I found that quite easy to understand. :) :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ahh ok, do you mean

```
DateTime a = DateTime.Now.AddDays(int.Parse(b));
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;


if(a.Date == d.Date)
   //awesome
```